# Insert "and" before last element in string

Tags: r, string, text

Say I have this string:

```
fruits <- c("apple", "pear", "orange", "banana", "melon")
```

I can collapse each element into a string like this:

```
cat(paste(fruits, collapse = ", "))
```

But how can I insert and before the last element? Note that my real strings vary in length.

Output should be:

```
apple, pear, orange, banana and melon
```

Comment: Just do `c(fruits[-length(fruits)], 'and')` and paste with `fruits[length(fruits)]`

Answer (score 6):

You may use sub

```
> cat(sub("(.*),", "\\1 and",paste(fruits, collapse = ", ")))
apple, pear, orange, banana and melon
```